# Bigcommerce is it possible to pull all bigcommerce files into a local environment where I can test changes locally?

Tags: bigcommerce

is it possible to push all files I have in bigcommerce into a github repo which I can clone and edit and test locally? And whenever I merge a new pull request to that repo, it automatically updates the website in production?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this can be done with [Github Actions](https://github.com/features/actions), as they can be set up to allow you to make changes locally then push your changes to the main GitHub repository. The actions can be set to automatically upload and apply the theme files to your BigCommerce store.

Some other ref docs for you can be found here:

- [Github Marketplace](https://github.com/marketplace?type=actions)
- [How to use Github actions](https://blog.bitsrc.io/what-are-github-actions-and-how-to-use-them-e89904201a41)
- [Stencil CLI
  Commands](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/installing-stencil-cli/stencil-cli-options-and-commands)